# libQGLViewer installation on MacOS 10.7.2: Asking for Qt3 Support?

Tags: c++, qt, qglwidget

I am trying to install libQGLViewer2.3.13 (recent version) on MacOS 10.7.2 but it is giving me these errors after compiling some part of libqglviewer:

```
...
In file included from computerPlayer.cpp:33:
    ui_computerPlayerInterface.Qt4.h:35:42: error: Qt3Support/Q3MimeSourceFactory:
    No such file or directory
    make[3]: *** [.obj/computerPlayer.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [sub-Viewer-make_default] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [sub-agora-make_default] Error 2
    make: *** [sub-examples-contribs-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Can somebody please tell me how to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlast I contacted QGLViewer Developers and they have fixed this problem. Please follow the instructions given on this link for installation:
http://www.libqglviewer.com/index.html

and to compile your own QGLViewer project please follow this link:
http://www.libqglviewer.com/compilation.html#pro

It explains how to create your own `.pro file` to generate the `Makefile`.